# Поиск по сайтам через Google Custom Search

Tags: веб-программирование, google-search, google-customsearch-api

Есть например 10 сайтов по которым нужно сделать поиск. Пытаюсь это сделать через Google Custom Search
Нужно что бы в поисковом запросе можно было указывать например 1 или несколько сайтов по которым нужно сделать поиск

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=ok&cx=ok&siteSearch=vseinstrumenti.ru&q=makita
```

За это отвечает вот этот параметр **siteSearch** Если указать один сайт то всё работает корректно, но как указать например несколько сайтов, то не работает.
пробовал вот так vseinstrumenti.ru;220-volt.ru пробовал через пробел, через ":" Тоже не работает. Параметры key и cx я убрал

Comment: Это настроивается в консоль Custom Search.

Answer (score 1):

```
"вот этот параметр" site:vk.com OR site:ru.stackoverflow.com
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Кул. Жаль только в яндексе не работает.